# MATCH on GUID in Neo4js

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I imported a CSV dump from MS SQL into Neo4j. One of the nodes has a GUID as a primary key, but when I try to do a match, I get no results although the row is there.

I tried the following query:

```
MATCH (n:User) where n.UserId = "006cbcc9-7452-4bd3-a1da-c9f96fb15ff9"  RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

And the result is:

```
Returned 0 rows in 11 ms.
```

But when I run the query on the first name of this particular user, I do get a result:

```
MATCH (n:User) where n.FirstName = "Bob"  RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

As you can see, the UserId matches with the one I tried to find:

```
UserId      006cbcc9-7452-4bd3-a1da-c9f96fb15ff9
FirstName   Bob
LastName    The Builder
```

So what should my query look like to match by `UserId` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two potential causes for this:

1) You have some hidden characters in the property value to verify this, run:

```
MATCH (n:User) where n.FirstName = "Bob"  
RETURN n.UserId, n.UserId='006cbcc9-7452-4bd3-a1da-c9f96fb15ff9', 
       n.FirstName, n.LastName 
LIMIT 25
```

In the second column returns a `false` then you might have some other invisible character(s) in your `UserId`.

2) By far less likely: Assuming you have a unique constraint on `:User` and `UserId`. Maybe - for a weird reason - your index is corrupted. Try to drop it and re-create it.

Comment: Both the UserId and the UserId='' columns are NULL

Comment: amend `,keys(n)` to the `RETURN` and send the output. My theory is that your CSV dump a) has BOM b) you're using `WITH HEADERS` and c) `UserId` is your first column - please check. If so, use some preprocessing for your csv to get rid of BOM.

Comment: more precisely, amend `'UserId' in keys(n)`.

Comment: `'UserId' in keys(n)` returns false.
I am using CSV dump, and yes, `UserID` is my first column and I am using `WITH HEADERS`

Comment: so check if your CSV contains a BOM - being pretty sure it does.

Comment: Thank you! I saved the file in Notepad++ as UTF-8 without BOM and now I can do a `where` on the first column